# Intensity of light that produces largest current in Photoelectric Effect + Stopping Voltage Question

Tags: photoelectric-effect

[image: For the Sodium metal, the Current produced by the cell is the highest when shined on by 196nm light - Not the highest, why is that? What determines the intensity of the light that creates the largest current?]

[image]

For the first image: For the Sodium metal, the Current produced by the cell is the highest when shined on by 196nm light - Not the highest, why is that? What determines the intensity of the light that creates the largest current?

For the second image: When I change the voltage of the battery the current stops increasing when the voltage reaches 0V. Even when I increase the voltage even higher the current does not increase. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The current doesn't increase further because light only ejects a limited number of electrons per unit of time, so increasing voltage doesn't increase number of electrons passed through the circuit per unit of time, which by definition is current. And when you supply negative voltage, some electrons are slowed or even stopped, which makes current smaller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain the first question too then: Why is the current produced by the cell highest when shined by 196nm light - not the highest frequency light?

Comment: I'm not sure for first question. This may be because absorption spectrum will be smaller for higher energy photons than for lower energy ones. To check this one would need absorption spectrum for your material.